# Edit Reply Message (comment) to a Discussion - SharePoint Online JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

I need to do this in JavaScript since the entire solution is current in JavaScript and this is the last part.

I need to be able to update a reply message (comment) to an existing discussion.  I am able to change the discussion fields but not the message fields.  I know the message and the discussion are two different content types and that the reply messages are under a folder for the discussion but I don't know how to edit the reply message.  (There is a utility to add the reply message but not to edit it).

This is a sample of the discussion (in the list) in which you can see there are 5 replies, I want to change the body text of one of the replies via JavaScript.

[Image of the Discussion Showing Replies I would like to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMG7p.png)

And for example, I want to change the message below:

[Image of Replies that I want to change the body text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDlCn.png)

I have tried to update using this code, but it only changes the discussion and not the message.

I have a feeling I need to tell the system to go into that folder to find the message and change its body text, but I am not sure how to do this and after a 2 day search on the interwebs, I can't find an answer.
Code that does not work:
function aeditListItem() {

```
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById('40b2fbd4-4f87-d92fb05f8044');  //ID changed to protect client

    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(getParameterByName('commentid'));

    oListItem.set_item('Body', document.getElementById("ideaDetails").value.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />'));

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );

}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
     alert('Item Updated: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Many Many THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently at the line:

```
this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(getParameterByName('commentid'));
```

`getParameterByName('commentid')` does not return the proper message id, make sure the message list item id is specified.

As a proof of concept the following example shows how to:

- find a message by body
- replace the message with a new body

Example

```
var listTitle = "Discussions";
var oldMessageBody = "";
var newMessageBody  = "";

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.getItems(createMessageFindQuery('Body',oldMessageBody));
ctx.load(items);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){

      if(items.get_count() == 1){
            var foundItem = items.getItemAtIndex(0);
            foundItem.set_item('Body',newMessageBody);
            foundItem.update();    

            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
              function(){
                  console.log("Updated");   
              },
              function(sender,args){
                  console.log(args.get_message());
              });

      }   
      else
         console.log('Not found or multiple items are found')
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });

});   


function createMessageFindQuery(fieldName,fieldVal){
      var qry = new SP.CamlQuery;
      qry.set_viewXml(String.format('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="{0}" /><Value Type="Text">{1}</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>',fieldName,fieldVal));
      return qry;
}
```